# copy div tag script to input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to copy div tag action to inputbox in click event.In div tag calender is displayed.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input id="datepicker" type="date" name="sample">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        inline: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Improve your question, it's not clear what you are asking. FYI, **IDs must** be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show datepicker on a click event like this :

```
<div id="datepickerContainer"> <!---- ID should be unique ---------->
</div>
<input id="datepicker" type="date" name="sample">

 <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
  });
  $('#datepickerContainer').on('click',function() { 
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('show'); 
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Wait, now i understand the question ;)

Comment: I guessed too, what he intended to ask ;)

Comment: Still have: `In div tag calender is displayed.` I guess OP wants calendar to be displyed in DIV in fact

Comment: I noticed `copy div tag action to inputbox in click event` , still unclear though